# How to train OpenAI model on your own dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, openai-api

I am creating a OpenAI model, where I have train it on my own dataset. Dataset has two columns. First column has English queries and it's corresponding N1QL queries in second column. I have to train my model in such a way, so that whenever I ask English query, model should be able to return me the N1QL query for it. As of now I have written a sample code using examples on google like below:

```
import openai

def generate_prompt(animal):
    return """Suggest three names for an animal that is a superhero.
Animal: Cat
Names: Captain Sharpclaw, Agent Fluffball, The Incredible Feline
Animal: Dog
Names: Ruff the Protector, Wonder Canine, Sir Barks-a-Lot
Animal: {}
Names:""".format(
        animal.capitalize()
    )

def query_openai_api(english_query):
    openai.api_key = config.OPENAI_API_KEY
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        model="text-davinci-003",
        prompt=generate_prompt(english_query),
        temperature=0.6,
    )
    print(response.choices[0].text)

query_openai_api("Cat")
```

This piece of code is working fine for me. But I ain't sure how I can use my dataset as I have dataset in a csv file. So please help me in modifying the generate_prompt function to utilize my dataset in queries.csv, which looks like below snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below:

```
def generate_prompt(english_query):
    query_str = """Suggest N1QL Query for an English Query."""
    df = pd.read_excel('queries.xlsx')
    for ind in df.index:
        query_str = query_str + """
English Query: {}
N1QL Query: {}""".format(df["English Query"][ind], df["N1QL Query"][ind])
    query_str = query_str + """
English Query: {}
N1QL Query:
""".format(english_query)
    return query_str
```